# Can't pass a Button as a parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, events

What I'm trying to do here is really simple but it's not working for me. I've looked up many examples of very similar or matching questions on stackoverflow and others and their solutions haven't worked for me.

Basically (in a very simplified form), I have a button with some text in it. I'd like it so when this button is clicked, a message box shows up displaying the text. However, I have 9 of these buttons (think numbers on a calculator), and I'd like to create a single method that handles all of these clicks, and outputs the correct text depending on the button.. which is why I need to pass the button as a parameter.

Here's the code I have for the method that handles it so far:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, Button b)
{
    MessageBox.Show(b.Text);
}
```

The above small code snippet is the same solution that others have used and had working. However, for me this code doesn't compile and shows an error that says **No overload for 'btn_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'**.

When I double click on that error, it takes me to the Designer.cs page for the form, and this is the line of code that has the error:

```
this.btnN7.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnN7_Click);
```

I have no clue what the overload and delegate parts mean, sorry I'm pretty new to this. I was thinking that maybe overload has to do with constructors but even if that's correct, I'm unsure of what the next step would be.

I have **System.Windows.Forms;** included properly so the issue shouldn't be that the Button object wasn't recognized.

If you could provide any insight as to what I'm missing or doing wrong, that'd be very sweet! Please let me know if you need any additional information to continue.

And lastly, this is unrelated to my issue but it's a small question that's been irking me ever since I started using VS a week ago: Are the control parameters **object sender** and **EventArgs e** that are automatically created for controller events even necessary? Most of the examples I've looked up online omit them. I've just kept them in since they were created by default but I don't really know what kind of function they provide, and I've never had to use those parameters in my methods.

Thanks all! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which is why I need to pass the button as a parameter.

You don't really have to create that extra parameter. What you need is already there.

`object sender` is a source of the event, so just call

```
var btn = (Button) sender;
MessageBox.Show(btn.Text);
```

and you should be fine.

> Are the control parameters object sender and EventArgs e that are automatically created for controller events even necessary?

So now you have a part of an answer for this question. The second part (`EventArgs`) are needed for passing additional information. Read more about event args on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @IsaiahLee I'm glad I could help. I will try to answer the rest of your questions as well.

Comment: `EventArgs` is *always* empty for a button click even, it will *never* contain any meaningful information, so it is in fact pointless.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, good point. I was trying to explain that it's not always useful.

Comment: Something peculiar I noticed was that even if EventArgs is always empty in this case, I have to include it as a parameter. If I try to remove it from the parameters and link an event to that method, it will just create a new method with the EventArgs in it. So, I guess at least for VS2010, it's unnecessary but necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use `sender` parameter.You can't subscribe an event handler if the method signature doesn't match with the `EventHandler` delegate.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var currentButton = sender as Button;
   if(currentButton != null) MessageBox.Show(currentButton.Text);
}
```

`sender` will be assigned to an object that triggers the event.So for instance when your `button2` is clicked, it will be assigned to `button2`.Ofcourse you need to attach this event handler to `button2`'s Click event.I have also used the `as` operator to ensure that a button is triggered the event.In the future if you call this method manually like `btn_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty)` then the *explicit cast* will throw an `InvalidCastException`.Using `as` operator is always better to avoid this.If the type of the `sender` is different than `Button` then `currentButton` will be **null**.

Comment: Just comparing your answer with Ondrej, using sender as Button is essentially the same thing as (Button) sender; right? Semantically is one way more "proper" than the other?

And also, you checked whether the button was null. Could you explain how a button is null? Would a button be null, for example, if it was disabled?

Thanks Selman!

Comment: This way is more proper since you avoid getting an exception like you would get in my case. But if you are sure that the sender is a button, you can do it my way.

Comment: @IsaiahLee Selmans' code will do nothing in the event that the object passed is not a button (i.e., if you attach this method as the handler of a non-button event, or call it directy).  The other answer will throw an exception.  In this case, I'd say it's quite clear that throwing an exception is preferable.  It's an ingrained assumption of this particular method that the sender is a button.  if it's not, then something is wrong.  Rather than sweeping the problem under the rug and ignoring it, you *want* it to yell loudly at you, making this the inferior solution.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Servy that makes a lot of sense to me. I'm going to mark Ondrej's input as the answer since it makes more sense to my specific case in hand, but I really learned from Selman's input as well. That's definitely something to keep in mind for the future, in case i'm creating methods that can be accessed by other objects or controllers. Thanks all! <3

Comment: "Using as operator is always better to avoid this" No, it's not.  In fact, it's not even true in this specific example, let alone every single case.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

- If you want to access to the button that fired the event, you can do it trough `sender`

  ```
  private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Button b = (Button)sender;
      MessageBox.Show(b.Text);
  }
  ```
- Otherwise, access directly through the button name (in case you know it)